# Subdomain redirection to folder without changing URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wildcard-subdomain

I have a primary domain which is pointed to primary folder like below

```
http://www.primary.com -> /var/www/html/primary
```

I need to make the below working without changing the URL to `http://www.primary.com/sub`

```
http://sub.primary.com -> /var/www/html/sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.primary\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^(.*)\.primary\.com /%1%{REQUEST_URI}  [NC,NE,L]
```